# RxJS execute two observables in sequence

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable

Say I have two observables `obs1` and `obs2`.

```
obs1.subscribe(res => { //do stuff with output1});
obs2.subscribe(res => { //do stuff with output2});
```

I want to subscribe to `obs2` only after `obs1` is finished execution. The only way I know is ugly:

```
obs1.pipe(finalize(() => {
  obs2.subscribe(res => { //do stuff with output2});
})).subscribe(res => {//do stuff with output1})
```

Is there a more elegant way? Adding a third `obs3` would make code very hard to read.

EDIT:
From previous answers it was not clear to me how to have data from individual observables. The following code does exactly what I want:

```
concat(
  obs1.pipe(tap( res => console.log(res))),
  obs2.pipe(tap( res => console.log(res)))
).subscribe()
```

What previous answers suggested was:

```
concat(obs1, obs2).subscribe(res => console.log(res))
```

but in this case the final response merges responses of `obs1` and `obs2` and I did not know how to separate it.

Comment: *"I want to subscribe to obs2 only after obs1 is finished execution"*. That's exactly what `concat` does.

Comment: So do you want to reopen this question or it's all right now?